# preventing an embedable iframe to take the client side down, when the source is down.

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an embedable form which I offer as a plugin. I make an embeddable iframe which other users can embed. 
We are hosted on EC2 and recently EC2 has been going down. So when our site goes down, either because of the server 
or because of any other error, the site which has the iframe embedded, that also goes down. How can we prevent it?

Comment: What do you mean by “the site which has the iframe embedded […] also goes down”? This site would likely display an error (timeout, e.g.) but still be otherwise functional?

Comment: that is the expected behavior, what happens is it does not load.

Comment: The parent site doesn’t load because of a failure to load the iframe content? Odd. Any chance the parent site is also hosted on EC2?

Comment: let me explain. I have a quiz widget, which you can embed via iframe which i provide. Once my site(the quiz site) goes down, the iframe when clicked on the site that embedded my widget also goes down. And no the other is not hosted on EC2.

Comment: Thanks, that’s what I'm after. Your widget goes down (of course, since it's served from your page), **not** the parent page.